# When load my unity scene on vmware windows virtual machine, the color/lightening of the scene randomly changes? It turns pink

Tags: unity, game-design, lighting

Hi I have a unity scene doing all it is suppose to on mac but I had to load that scene on vmware windows virtual machine and when I did that, the color or the lighting of the scene was randomly changed and I don't know how to fix that. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Virtualization is rarely good at emulating 3d graphics APIs.

Comment: Are you using `Unity Mode` in VMware? Also, are you using VMware locally or remotely?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I am not using Unity Mode in VMware and I am using VMware locally.

Comment: Does the lighting turn pink everytime you run it? In that case the pink colour might indicate a problem with a missing texture, missing bake, or something in that area. You might want to check if your project compiles properly